# npm doesn't work in jenkins over docker container

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, http-status-code-403, cacerts

Well I have a debian with docker 25.0.1 and this containers , gitlab, jenkins, nexus and wildfly, nexus and wildfly forget it.
I am tryin to clone from gitlab to jenkins, and all was ok, after that I did maven and all ok, buy after that , the next step is make npm install, npm run build, npm start but doen´t work.

Jenkins gives me this error with local installation /usr/bin/node don´t find and in the jenkins global tools tells me this:

```
/usr/bin/node is not a directory on the Jenkins controller (but perhaps it exists on some agents)
```

I tried to make another installation but the error is the next:

```
+ npm install
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tslib/-/tslib-2.5.0.tgz
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.
npm ERR! 403 
npm ERR! 403 It was specified as a dependency of '@antv/color-util'
npm ERR! 403
```

I tried to update nodejs and no change, remake the certs with mkcert and nothing, and make this npm config set strict-ssl false but do not work.

I expect that npm install and npm run build works.
¿Any idea?

Best regards to all.